# Roasting pyrite - product magnetite

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

When roasting pyrite, the products are usually Fe$_{2}$O$_{3}$ and SO$_{2}$, but is it possible to get magnetite and SO$_{2}$ from roasting pyrite? Thanks for answers.

Comment: No. The roasting must go all the way to Fe2O3, ie Fe+3, to get rid of all the S in the pyrite.